# bitcoin to currency converter and it's reverse in php

Tags: php, api, currency, bitcoin

I am using [Bitcoin Currency Converter](https://btc-e.com/api/documentation) in PHP.So that I can convert Bitcoin to any currency (say USD) and Any Currency (say USD) to Bitcoins.

Is there any api to do it ?? Till now I am using this url to convert any currency to Bitcoins `https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=83.652`

but how to do it's reverse (convert from bitcoins to currency).Also I don't know whether this result is correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I previously used the MtGox API to achieve this available as [HTTP](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/HTTP) or [streaming web socket](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/Streaming)

EDIT:

Ok, you can get the value by doing this:

```
//set currency
$currency = 'USD';
//get json response
$return = file_get_contents('http://data.mtgox.com/api/1/BTC'.$currency.'/ticker_fast');
//decode it (into an array rather than object [using 'true' parameter])
$info = json_decode($return, true);
//access the dollar value
$value = $info['return']['last_local']['value'];
```

It's a public API so you don't need to authenticate, you just get the contents of the page which is in JSON format and decode it into an array and access the value element.

You now know that 1 BTC = 90.20505 dollars - so therefore 1 dollar is equal to 0.0110858 Bitcoins. (1 / 90.20505).

You can do this with any currency.

Voila

**UPDATE:**

For new readers of this question, this solution no longer works based on MtGox going under **see Nathan's working solution below.**

Comment: it is giving me the login error while I am already logged in  array(1) { ["error"]=> string(17) "Must be logged in" } array(1) { ["error"]=> string(17) "Must be logged in" }

Comment: also I think it is not for conversion api , it is used for sell/buy bitcoins ???

Comment: You can use ticker to get the current value of a bitcoin in a currency of your choice, you can then use that information to work out the conversion rate between ie USD to BTC, and reverse it accordingly

Comment: it is giving me the login error while I am already logged in array(1) { ["error"]=> string(17) "Must be logged in" } array(1) { ["error"]=> string(17) "Must be logged in" }

Comment: could you give me some more information about what your doing to get that error?

Comment: I am using this PHP code https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/HTTP I have written my api and secret key

Comment: Sorry I linked to incorrect place: try this  https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/HTTP/v1

Comment: So query: http://data.mtgox.com/api/1/BTCUSD/ticker for USD value (change USD to another currency code (others are USD, AUD, CAD, CHF, CNY, DKK, EUR, GBP, HKD, JPY, NZD, PLN, RUB, SEK, SGD, THB)

Comment: Sorry I did not get how to use this api.Can you please give me an example. thanks

Comment: Ok will edit my answer one moment

Comment: okay. I am waiting thanks!

Comment: I will get values like this http://data.mtgox.com/api/1/BTCUSD/ticker but which one is main value in this and how will I extract it

Comment: Please see the EDIT in my origional answer, I have provided you all the code to do this

Comment: Also I have one more way to get this, is it ok??? $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://data.mtgox.com/api/1/BTC'.$currency.'/ticker_fast');
$res = curl_exec($ch);
echo $res;

Comment: You can use CURL if you prefer I can't test it at the moment, but if it works it works! Mine definitely works though so could you accept my answer please :P

Comment: i will accept your answer but it is giving me the wrong answer, it is giving me 9078982 always while value is changing within minute and on bitcoin site it is 84.34 of i bitcoin

and secondly I want to convert usd to bitcoin as i wrote in my question.The answer you provided me is opposite

Comment: I explained in the answer how to do this: if 1 bitcoin is 90.78982, then to calculate what 1 USD is in bitcoins - 1/ 90.78982 = 0.0110144 . So then times that by the number of dollars. It does change as when I tested it was 90.2

Comment: it's ok I got this how to get bitcoins from usd but i think value we are getting about 90.2 is not correct you can check at this url https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=89     as you know one decimal error value means a lot in such cases. :)

Comment: Its not working now..

Comment: @NathanSrivi mtgox fell over a while back

Comment: Ok @JohnnyFaldo now my example is working now. check it

Comment: @NathanSrivi nice one have pointed to it in my edit

Answer (score 4):

Use this its working good. http://data.mtgox.com/api/1/BTC is not working now

```
<?php
$currency = 'USD';
$url = 'https://bitpay.com/api/rates/'.$currency;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.15) Gecko/20080623 Firefox/2.0.0.15") ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result= curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$info = json_decode($result, true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($info);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I extracted a feature from a recent project i created that solves the same use case and released it as open source framework agnostic php library.

https://github.com/jimmerioles/bitcoin-currency-converter-php

A simple, lightweight, extensible and fast bitcoin to currency converter and vice versa based on current exchange rates from your chosen provider: Coinbase, Coindesk, Bitpay and etc.

### Features

- Convert Bitcoin to any currency (ISO 4217 fiat or another cryptocurrency)
- Convert any currency (ISO 4217 fiat or another cryptocurrency) to Bitcoin
- Supports different exchange rates providers: Coinbase, Coindesk, Bitpay
- Baked-in caching (PSR16 compliant, swappable with your own or your framework's)

### Install

Via Composer:

```
$ composer require jimmerioles/bitcoin-currency-converter-php
```

### Usage

Convert Bitcoin to any currency (fiat or crypto):

```
use Jimmerioles\BitcoinCurrencyConverter\Converter;

$convert = new Converter;              // uses Coinbase as default provider
echo $convert->toCurrency('USD', 0.5); // 2000.00
echo $convert->toCurrency('LTC', 0.5); // 10.12345678
```

or use helper for convenience:

```
// uses Coinbase as default provider
echo to_currency('USD', 0.5); // 2000.00
echo to_currency('LTC', 0.5); // 10.12345678
```

Convert any currency (fiat or crypto) to Bitcoin:

```
use Jimmerioles\BitcoinCurrencyConverter\Converter;

$convert = new Converter;         // uses Coinbase as default provider
echo $convert->toBtc(100, 'USD'); // 0.12345678
echo $convert->toBtc(20, 'LTC');  // 1.12345678
```

or use helper for convenience:

```
// uses Coinbase as default provider
echo to_btc(100, 'USD'); // 0.12345678
echo to_btc(20, 'LTC');  // 2.12345678
```

Specifying exchange rates provider:

```
use Jimmerioles\BitcoinCurrencyConverter\Converter;
use Jimmerioles\BitcoinCurrencyConverter\Provider\CoinbaseProvider;
use Jimmerioles\BitcoinCurrencyConverter\Provider\CoindeskProvider;
use Jimmerioles\BitcoinCurrencyConverter\Provider\BitpayProvider;

$convert = new Converter(new CoinbaseProvider);
$convert = new Converter(new CoindeskProvider);
$convert = new Converter(new BitpayProvider);
```

or use helper for convenience:

```
echo to_currency('USD', 0.5, new CoindeskProvider); // 2000.00
echo to_currency('LTC', 0.5, new BitpayProvider);   // 10.12345678
echo to_btc(100, 'USD', new CoindeskProvider);      // 0.12345678
echo to_btc(20, 'LTC', new BitpayProvider);         // 2.12345678
```

Specifying cache expire time (ttl) on provider:

```
new CoinbaseProvider($httpClient, $psr16CacheImplementation, 5); // cache expires in 5mins, defaults to 60mins
```